# Toolbar not getting invisible appropriately. Please see details

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout

I want an invisible toolbar but I want the back arrow and title to be displayed.

For achieving this, I did the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.abc.xyz.AboutActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:background="@color/toolbarTransparent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/header_about"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/a"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:src="@drawable/a"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/header_about"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"/>

    <include layout="@layout/content_about"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

But, I'm getting the following result (Look how toolbar is still appearing to be there):

[image]

I want the toolbar to get invisible and only the title and back arrow to be shown.

Please let me know how can I achieve that.

Sorry for bad format of the question. I'm still a beginner here.

Comment: Set background of toolbar to transparent it will do the trick for you

Answer (score 1):

AppBarLayout has default elevation value and that is why you can see shadow. You can set AppBarLayout elevation to 0dp

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
     app:elevation="0dp"
     android:background="@color/toolbarTransparent">
```

or just remove AppBarLayout. Toolbar is transparent by default.

If you want to use AppBarLayout with transparent background on Android Lolipop version and greater - set outline provider to BACKGROUND like below:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    appBarLayout.setOutlineProvider(ViewOutlineProvider.BACKGROUND);
}
```

In this case when your background is transparent shadow will be not visible.

Comment: doing `app:elevation="0dp"` is making the title and back arrow disappear too.

Answer (score 0):

please check the android manifest file it should have AppTheme.NoActionBar then u will be able to hide it